# Airflow Generate Dynamic Tasks in Single DAG , Task N+1 is Dependent on TaskN

Tags: python, airflow

When generating tasks dynamically, I need to have Task 2 be dependent of Task 1, Task1 >> Task 2 or task2.set_upstream(task1).

Since the task_ids are evaluated, or seem to be upfront, I cannot set the dependency in advance, any help would be appreciated.

The Component(I) tasks generate fine, except that they all run at once.

```
for i in range(1,10):
  task_id='Component'+str(i)
  task_id = BashOperator(
  task_id='Component'+str(i),
  bash_command="echo  {{ ti.xcom_pull task_ids='SomeOtherTaskXcom', key='return_value') }} -z " + str(i) ,
  xcom_push=True,
  dag=dag) 
  ?????.set_upstream(??????)
```

Comment: Probably a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38022323/1531971 (If not, tell us _why_. Show your research.)

Comment: That entry is DAG in scope, I'm looking specifically for Task sequencing, the below code works fine for dynamic parallel tasking, but not serial

Comment: This is the sort of detail that should be put in the question via an [edit].

Comment: Looks like Scheduling and Triggers might be the ticket then

Answer (score 30):

**For Airflow>=2.3**

You can use **[Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-with-non-taskflow-operators)** feature where Dynamic Tasks are natively supported

```py
BashOperator.partial(task_id="Component", do_xcom_push=True).expand(
    bash_command=[
        "echo  {{ ti.xcom_pull task_ids='SomeOtherTaskXcom', key='return_value') }} -z " + str(i)
        for i in range(0, 10)
    ]
)
```

**For Airflow<2.3**

Use the following code:

```
a = []
for i in range(0,10):
    a.append(BashOperator(
        task_id='Component'+str(i),
        bash_command="echo  {{ ti.xcom_pull task_ids='SomeOtherTaskXcom', key='return_value') }} -z " + str(i) ,
        xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag))
    if i not in [0]: 
        a[i-1] >> a[i]
```

Using a `DummyOperator`, the codes looks like:

```
a = []
for i in range(0,10):
    a.append(DummyOperator(
        task_id='Component'+str(i),
        dag=dag))
    if i not in [0]: 
        a[i-1] >> a[i]
```

This would generate the following DAG:

[image]

Comment: Thanks !  Just what I was looking for, works perfectly as described above. To have the dynamic steps execute after another step just add a[0].set_upstream(somePreviousTask)

Comment: Wow! Very cool. Is it common/recommended to define operators in lists like this?

Comment: @kjmerf Yes it is common

Comment: how can I make that for loop range to be dependent of the result inside an operator operation?

Comment: @kaxil: Great answer! I had one clarification question though. Why `if i not in [0]` instead of `i != 0`?

Answer (score 9):

You can follow a pattern like this:

```
with dag:

d1 = DummyOperator(task_id='kick_off_dag')

for i in range(0, 5):
    d2 = DummyOperator(task_id='generate_data_{0}'.format(i))
    d1 >> d2
```

This will generate 5 tasks downstream from d1.

Comment: That works to run the 5 tasks in parallel after d1, what I'm looking for is to have the tasks run sequentially, like this :   d1 >> generate_data_1 >> generate_data_2 >> generate_data_3 >> generate_data_4 >> generate_data_5

Comment: set_upstream takes a task or task list, the example above pushes a task list in which ends up executing them in parallel

Comment: Thank you! I searched in so many places just to find your answer which is a simple yet effective pattern. This was exactly my situation: One task that needed to run before a group of dynamically generated tasks in parallel, within the same DAG. My mistake was defining the relationship outside of the loop instead of inside.

Answer (score 0):

Use [chain](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#relationship-builders)

```py
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain

ops = []
for i in range(0,10):
    ops.append(DummyOperator(
        task_id=f"Component_{i}",
        dag=dag))

chain(ops)
```