# Apache Airflow - split task in multiple parallel tasks where each task takes portion of the list as input argument

Tags: python, airflow

Let's say I have list with 100 items called `mylist`.

I have function that performs certain operation with each element of the list.
I order to speed things up I want define `n` parallel tasks.
Each task should take `100/n` list items and process them.

I understand all about executors and core settings which I need to change to enable parallelism, I need some basic pointer on how to set tasks right.

My idea is to build it like this:

```
imports...

mylist = [item0, item2,...,item99]
n=5


def myfunction(sub_list):
    """This is a function that will run within the DAG execution"""
    """Procesing list elements"""


# Generate 5 tasks
for i in range(1,len(lst), n):
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='myfunction_' + str(i),
        python_callable=myfunction,
        op_kwargs={'sub_list': mylist[i:i + n]},
        dag=dag,
    )

 task
```

I've assebmled this algorithm according to documentation.
Is this proper way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airflow Generate Dynamic Tasks in Single DAG , Task N+1 is Dependent on TaskN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558018/airflow-generate-dynamic-tasks-in-single-dag-task-n1-is-dependent-on-taskn)

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov tasks should run in parallel, in that example they are running sequentially.

Comment: Just scroll down https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558172/6942134

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov this question deals with sequential task running. I cannot mark it as resolving to my question since it would be confusing to people. It's true that second answer confirms my proposition of answer - which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

My initial proposition is correct, so you can run tasks in parallel while all tasks are using certain portion of the list as input like this:

```
imports...

mylist = [item0, item2,...,item99]
n=5 # Number of parallel tasks, this is also number of splits that we are doing on list. 


def myfunction(sub_list):
    """This is a function that will run within the DAG execution"""
    """Procesing list elements"""


# Generate some dummy initial task
d1 = DummyOperator(task_id='kick_off_dag')

# Generate 5 tasks
for i in range(1,len(mylist), n):
    five_parallelTasks = PythonOperator(
        task_id='myfunction_' + str(i),
        python_callable=myfunction,
        op_kwargs={'sub_list': mylist[i:i + n]},
        dag=dag,
    )

 
d1 >> five_parallelTasks
```

Where `range(1,len(lst), n)` is iterating over list by every `n-th` element. This allows us to define input in each task as `mylist[i:i + n]`

Comment: Should `d1 >> five_parallelTasks` be within the for? Or am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: @KevinWoodward some education about creating DAGs is needed: https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-dag-creating-your-first-dag-in-5-minutes/

Comment: This reassigns `five_parallelTasks` within the loop without using it. It's also not being added to a list. Your final line will simply add the dependency between `d1` and the task from the result of the last iteration of your loop.

Comment: @KevinWoodward not really, my solution is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67623392/2119941 put it in practice and see if it works.